# Is $S=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]:x,y\in\mathbb Q\}$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let  $S=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]:x,y\in\mathbb Q\}$. Whether  $S$ is Lebesgue measurable? Or $S$ is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ is a countable union of zero-measure elements, so $S$ has zero-measure too.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $S$ is a  countable set.